# How to get IllegalArgumentException while fetching values from tree set?

Tags: java, treeset

As per the tailset definition

> "A tailSet() method of TreeSet class returns the element present in
> the set, which is greater than or equal to fromElement. If the passed
> value is outside of the range, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown"

but when i am trying to implement it, its returning blank set instead of throwing IllegalArgumentException.

```
public class SampleSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NavigableSet obj = new TreeSet();
        NavigableSet obj1 = new TreeSet();
        obj.add(4);
        obj.add(6);
        obj.add(9);
        obj.add(2);
        System.out.println(obj);
        obj1 = (NavigableSet) obj.tailSet(9,false);
        System.out.println(obj1);
    }

}
```

Please explain what is the way to get IllegalArgumentException while fetching. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you see that text?  The closest thing I can find in [the method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html#tailSet(E,boolean)) is: “The returned set will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` on an attempt to insert an element outside its range.”  You have not attempted to insert an element into the tailset.

Comment: @VGR It's not the same quote, but [SortedSet.tailSet()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html#tailSet(E)) says "IllegalArgumentException - if this set itself has a restricted range, and fromElement lies outside the bounds of the range" under "Throws".

Answer (score 0):

I used your code as a basis. The range can be determined by a [subSet() (javaDoc)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet(E,boolean,E,boolean)):

```java
NavigableSet<E> subSet​(E fromElement, boolean fromInclusive, E toElement, boolean toInclusive)
```

Using `tailSet()` on this subset with an out-of-range value will cause an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```java
import java.util.NavigableSet;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NavigableSet<Integer> obj = new TreeSet<>();
        NavigableSet<Integer> obj1 = new TreeSet<>();
        obj.add(4);
        obj.add(6);
        obj.add(9);
        obj.add(2);
        System.out.println(obj);
        obj1 = obj.tailSet(9,false);
        System.out.println(obj1);

        obj1 = obj.subSet(4, true, 6, true);
        obj1 = obj1.tailSet(9,false);       // 9 is out of range

    }
}
```

Result:

```
[2, 4, 6, 9]
[]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromKey out of range
        at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$AscendingSubMap.tailMap(TreeMap.java:1880)
        at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.tailSet(TreeSet.java:350)
        at Testing.main(Testing.java:989)
```